# Javafx Combo Box data population

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I would like to populate some data within a combo box. This works fine. However, I then want to dynamically change the data in the combo box.

Currently I have a table, and in the combo boxes I display unique values of the data in the table columns. Now the table data is stored in a Static observable list variable. I want to change the data in the combo box depending on the data that is displayed in the table. That is, if the static observable list which stores table data changes I want to change the combo box data without manual intervention.

Is this possible without having separate static variables for combo boxes too?

Comment: Please post some code. It is unclear why anything would need to be static (and it's almost always a bad idea in UI code).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm lets see, so we have your TableView data:

`ObservableList<MyData> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

and your ComboBox data:

`ObservableList<MyData> comboboxData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

If you want to link both together, the easiest way to achieve this, is using a FilteredList:

`ObservableList<MyData> comboboxData = tableData.filtered(predicate);`

So whenever the `predicate` or the `tableData` changes, these changes will be reflected in the `comboboxData` without any further doing. You now just have to write a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) that is able to filter the table data leaving only the combobox entries you want to display.

---

If however you want to display only the distinct values of the `tableData` in your ComboBox, this won't be so easy with a simple Predicate.
This is a very ugly approach using a Listener and a Set to update the ComboBox list:

```
ObservableList<String> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<String> comboBoxData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

tableData.addListener((Observable change) -> {
    Set<String> distinct = new HashSet<>(tableData);
    comboBoxData.setAll(distinct);
});
```

This will most probably lead to performance problems when your table contains large data sets, but for smaller sets this should do just fine.